Pyperclip keyboard listener on Mac in Spyder is blocked from access
When running pyperclip/pynput keyboard listener in Anaconda Spyder I receive the following message:
"This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients."
I've added Python, Anaconda and spyder to the list of accessibility clients as well as Input monitoring clients. As also suggested here: Keyboard Listener for Mac using Python

However the same problem persists.
The program work when launching it from the terminal as root, but I would like it to work in Spyder for quick changes in the code.
Could it be that spyder is using a different python than the one I have granted access to? If so, how would I go about finding the right one?
